# Json Serializer with multiple JsonProperty Newtonsoft.Json

Tags: json, asp.net-core, .net-core, serialization, json.net

I have an entity class with JsonProperty attribute as follows:

```
public class Book
{
    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public long BookId { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("name")]
    public string BookName { get; set; }
}
```

I want to deserialize this from JSON string to the entity. Due to JsonProperty `id` & `name`, the json should have the id/name schema and in that case the deserialize works perfectly (as expected). But in some cases, the json string can also have `BookId` and `BookName`. Can I have multiple JsonProperty attributes to handle this? Or is there a way to let the serializer know, that if not id then deserialize using BookId? Or any other way to handle this use case?

Comment: This link might help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43714050/multiple-jsonproperty-name-assigned-to-single-property

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the property name before deserializing the json.

```cs
var book = @"
    [
      {
        'id': 123456789,
        'name': 'book1'
      },
      {
        'BookId': 1234567,
        'BookName': 'book2'
      }
    ]
    ";

    var after = book.Replace("BookId", "id").Replace("BookName", "name");
    var sbook = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Book>>(after);
```

Then you can get the entire deserialization object.

[image]

Comment: @Anish Unnikrishnan, can this help you?

Comment: String.replace is a clever technique. Could be use full in a different scenario. But it didn't fit my use case. Thanks anyway Karney.

Comment: @AnishUnnikrishnan, but what is your scenario?

Comment: I am getting data from a DB call. And might have characters similar to key in the actual data itself. String.Replace will also replace the actual leading to bugs in the future.

Comment: There is no configuration to map the multiple properties, so you have to handle it manully.

Answer (score 0):

You could solve this by defining alternative properties, which redirects to existing ones. For example,

```
public class Book
{
    [JsonProperty("bookId")]
    public long BookId { get; set; }
    
    [JsonProperty("id")]
    private long Id
    {
        get => BookId;
        set => BookId = value;
    }
    [JsonProperty("bookName")]
    public string BookName { get; set; }
    
    [JsonProperty("name")]
    private string Name
    {
        get => BookName;
        set => BookName = value;
    }
}
```

[Demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/3zKdlY)

Comment: Note that if both properties are present in the Json, only the last one will be preserved.