# Serialization and Deserialization HttpClient payload in C#

Tags: c#, .net, rest, json.net, json-deserialization

> I have to retrieve some verbose json data from an API using System.Net.Http.HttpClient. In order to correctly deserialize these data in the desired format I have to remove white spaces and special character (such as accents and underscores) in the property names (not in values) and, after that, remove the pair "property name" : "property values" not present in the desiderd format. How can I achieve this?

I've tried something like this that did not work:

```
                string apiResponse = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                var jsonSerializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings
                {
                    ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver()
                };
                var interimObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ExpandoObject>(apiResponse);
                var myJsonOutput = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(interimObject,  jsonSerializerSettings);
                var responseData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<APILindeResponseWrapper<PatientData>>(myJsonOutput);
```

In particular, white spaces were eliminated.
My APILindeResponseWrapper is:

```
{
    public class APILindeResponseWrapper<T>
    {
        public string Status { get; set; }
        public List<DataWrapper<T>> Data { get; set; }
        public string Message;

    }

    public partial class DataWrapper<T>
    {
        public Timestamp Timestamp { get; set; }
        public T Data;
        
    }
    public partial class Timestamp
    {
        public string Type;
        public string[] Data;

    }
}
```

My PatientData is:

```
    public class PatientData
    {
        public PatientData() { }
       
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "{0} Must Be Filled")]
        public string? No { get; set; }
        
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "{0} Must Be Filled")]
        public string? Nome { get; set; }
        
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "{0} Must Be Filled")]
        public string? FirstName { get; set; }
        
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "{0} Must Be Filled")]
        public string? Surname { get; set; }  
        public string? CittaNascita { get; set; }
        
        public DateTime? DataDiNascita { get; set; }
        
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "{0} Must Be Filled")]
        public int? Sesso { get; set; }   
        public string? CodiceFiscale { get; set; }
       
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "{0} Must Be Filled")]
        public string? Indirizzo { get; set; }   
        public string? Frazione { get; set; }
        
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "{0} Must Be Filled")]
        public string? CAP { get; set; }
        
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "{0} Must Be Filled")]
        public string? Città { get; set; }
        
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "{0} Must Be Filled")]
        public string? Provincia { get; set; }   
        public string? TelefonoDiConsegna { get; set; }
        public string? IndirizzoResidenza { get; set; }
        public string? CAPResidenza { get; set; }
        public string? CittaResidenza { get; set; }
        public string? ProvinciaResidenza { get; set; }
       
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "{0} Must Be Filled")]
        public string? ShortDim5 { get; set; }
        public DateTime? DataAutorizzazione { get; set; }
        
        public DateTime? DataScadenza { get; set; }
       
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "{0} Must Be Filled")]
        public string? CustomerNo { get; set; }
        
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "{0} Must Be Filled")]
        public string? ShortDim4 { get; set; }
              
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "{0} Must Be Filled")]
        public string? StatoDelServizio { get; set; }
        
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "{0} Must Be Filled")]
        public string? ContractNo { get; set; }
        public DateTime? DataDiInstallazione { get; set; }
        
        public string?  Medico { get; set; }
       
    }
```

An example of API response from postman is:

```
{
    "status": 200,
    "data": [
        {
            "timestamp": {
                "type": "Buffer",
                "data": [
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    1,
                    179,
                    245,
                    49,
                    202
                ]
            },
            "Customer No_": "M037984",
            "Name": "ASST PAVIA",
            "No_": "P260339",
            "Codice Ricerca": "COMASCHI ROMOLO 19300523",
            "Nome": "COMASCHI ROMOLO",
            "Nome2": "",
            "Data di Nascita": "1930-05-23T00:00:00.000Z",
            "Luogo di Nascita": "",
            "Sesso": 1,
            "Codice Fiscale": "CMSRML30E23M119E",
            "Indirizzo": "CASA TORREGGIANI 8",
            "Città": "MONTECALVO VERSIGGIA",
            "CAP": "27047",
            "Provincia": "PV",
            "Cod_ Regione": "LOM",
            "Codice Paese": "IT",
            "Global Dimension 1 Code": "DOM221000",
            "Global Dimension 2 Code": "DOM202",
            "Contract No_": "CNT037453",
            "Address 2": "",
            "Ultimo Stato": "2019-05-08T00:00:00.000Z",
            "Stato del Servizio": "D",
            "Sospesa Fatturazione": 1,
            "Sospeso Servizio": 1,
            "Gita": "",
            "Giro": 0,
            "A Giro": 0,
            "Cadenza": 0,
            "Tipo Consegna": "",
            "Data Ultimo Aggior_ Consegna": "1753-01-01T00:00:00.000Z",
            "Prossima Consegna Prevista": "1753-01-01T00:00:00.000Z",
            "Time Slot": "",
            "Indirizzo di Consegna": "CASA TORREGGIANI 8",
            "CAP di Consegna": "27047",
            "Comune di Consegna": "MONTECALVO VERSIGGIA",
            "Provincia di Consegna": "PV",
            "Cod_ Regione di Consegna": "LOM",
            "Telefono di Consegna": "3403604306",
            "Piano": "",
            "NrInterno": "",
            "Ascensore": 0,
            "Data Ultima Modifica": "2019-05-09T00:00:00.000Z",
            "Flusso Prescritto": 0,
            "Oredie": 0,
            "Flusso Reale": 0,
            "Tipo di Fornitura": 0,
            "Prodotto": "",
            "Apparecchiatura": "",
            "Posizione Sanitaria": "",
            "Somministrazione": "",
            "Data di Installazione": "2019-04-17T00:00:00.000Z",
            "Data di Ritiro": "1753-01-01T00:00:00.000Z",
            "Data Ultima Consegna": "1753-01-01T00:00:00.000Z",
            "Medico": "SPRT",
            "ASL": "",
            "Distretto": "",
            "Data Autorizzazione": "1753-01-01T00:00:00.000Z",
            "Data Scadenza": "1753-01-01T00:00:00.000Z",
            "Protocollo": "",
            "Autorizzazione": "",
            "Ricetta": "",
            "Altro": "",
            "Numerazione": "",
            "Bloccato": 0,
            "ID_Utente": "LINDE\\IT00F4",
            "Flusso Strumenti": 0,
            "Flusso Ossigeno": 0,
            "Parente stretto": "",
            "MedicoImport": "",
            "ProdottoImport": "",
            "Diagnosi": "",
            "SospesoImport": "",
            "StrumentoImport": "",
            "DescrStrumento": "",
            "FRI": 0,
            "ORI": 0,
            "Informazioni Ambientali": "",
            "Unità Operativa": "",
            "Flusso Accessori": 0,
            "ASLN": "",
            "DistrettoN": "",
            "Totale Sospeso": 0,
            "Tot Sospeso FT": 0,
            "Dotazione": 0,
            "Usa Consumo Reale": 0,
            "Conta": 0,
            "Nr_ Farmacia": "",
            "Tipo Ventilazione": 0,
            "Tipo di Servizio": 0,
            "Tipologia": 1,
            "Erma": 0,
            "Ult_ Cons_ POT": "1753-01-01T00:00:00.000Z",
            "Note Palmare": "",
            "Provenienza": "",
            "ShortDim3": "ASL",
            "ShortDim4": "020400",
            "ShortDim5": "GOX",
            "ShortDim6": "010909000",
            "ShortDim9": "",
            "ShortDim10": "P260339",
            "Shortdim12": "CA",
            "Frazione": "",
            "Zona": "",
            "Venditore": "",
            "Filiale": "",
            "Agente": "",
            "ASLOLD": "",
            "DistrettoOLD": "",
            "SomministrazioneOld": "",
            "MedicoOLD": "",
            "CatPAZOLD": "",
            "StrumentoOLD": "",
            "Sync Date Modified": "2019-05-09T09:21:44.473Z",
            "First Name": "ROMOLO",
            "Middle Name": "",
            "Surname": "COMASCHI",
            "Initials": "",
            "Installation Module": 0,
            "ASL Code": "",
            "Città Nascita": "",
            "CAP Nascita": "",
            "E-mail": "",
            "Data ultima assistenza": "1753-01-01T00:00:00.000Z",
            "Patient Type": 1,
            "STP Code": "",
            "CAP Iscr_ Sanitaria": "",
            "City Iscr_ Sanitaria": "",
            "Indirizzo Residenza": "CASA TORREGGIANI 8",
            "Città Residenza": "MONTECALVO VERSIGGIA",
            "CAP Residenza": "27047",
            "Provincia Residenza": "PV",
            "Cod_ Regione Residenza": "LOM",
            "Codice Paese Residenza": "IT",
            "Standard Next Deliv_ Date": 0,
            "User Filter Dim_ 1": "DOM221000",
            "Patient Id": "",
            "Patient Profile Code": "",
            "Istat Code": "018096",
            "Patologia": "",
            "RecID": {
                "type": "Buffer",
                "data": [
                    96,
                    234,
                    0,
                    0,
                    2,
                    123,
                    255,
                    80,
                    0,
                    50,
                    0,
                    54,
                    0,
                    48,
                    0,
                    51,
                    0,
                    51,
                    0,
                    57,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0
                ]
            },
            "Range Of Supports Code": "",
            "Service Starting Date": "1753-01-01T00:00:00.000Z",
            "Service Expiration Date": "1753-01-01T00:00:00.000Z",
            "Service Item No_": "",
            "Service Order No_": "",
            "RecGUID": "197FA2DE-7410-45CF-B36B-53E808D37497",
            "Delivery Type": ""
        },
        {
            "timestamp": {
                "type": "Buffer",
                "data": [
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    1,
                    180,
                    115,
                    47,
                    230
                ]
            },
            "Customer No_": "M037984",
            "Name": "ASST PAVIA",
            "No_": "P260347",
            "Codice Ricerca": "MERALDI LUIGI 19310523",
            "Nome": "MERALDI LUIGI",
            "Nome2": "",
            "Data di Nascita": "1931-05-23T00:00:00.000Z",
            "Luogo di Nascita": "",
            "Sesso": 1,
            "Codice Fiscale": "MRLLGU31E23I968J",
            "Indirizzo": "VIA CARDUCCI 16C",
            "Città": "PORTALBERA",
            "CAP": "27040",
            "Provincia": "PV",
            "Cod_ Regione": "LOM",
            "Codice Paese": "IT",
            "Global Dimension 1 Code": "DOM221000",
            "Global Dimension 2 Code": "DOM202",
            "Contract No_": "CNT037453",
            "Address 2": "",
            "Ultimo Stato": "2019-05-13T00:00:00.000Z",
            "Stato del Servizio": "SOS",
            "Sospesa Fatturazione": 1,
            "Sospeso Servizio": 1,
            "Gita": "",
            "Giro": 0,
            "A Giro": 0,
            "Cadenza": 0,
            "Tipo Consegna": "",
            "Data Ultimo Aggior_ Consegna": "1753-01-01T00:00:00.000Z",
            "Prossima Consegna Prevista": "1753-01-01T00:00:00.000Z",
            "Time Slot": "",
            "Indirizzo di Consegna": "VIA CARDUCCI 16C",
            "CAP di Consegna": "27040",
            "Comune di Consegna": "PORTALBERA",
            "Provincia di Consegna": "PV",
            "Cod_ Regione di Consegna": "LOM",
            "Telefono di Consegna": "3351028031",
            "Piano": "",
            "NrInterno": "",
            "Ascensore": 0,
            "Data Ultima Modifica": "2019-05-08T00:00:00.000Z",
            "Flusso Prescritto": 0,
            "Oredie": 0,
            "Flusso Reale": 0,
            "Tipo di Fornitura": 0,
            "Prodotto": "",
            "Apparecchiatura": "",
            "Posizione Sanitaria": "",
            "Somministrazione": "",
            "Data di Installazione": "2019-05-13T00:00:00.000Z",
            "Data di Ritiro": "1753-01-01T00:00:00.000Z",
            "Data Ultima Consegna": "1753-01-01T00:00:00.000Z",
            "Medico": "SPRT",
            "ASL": "",
            "Distretto": "",
            "Data Autorizzazione": "1753-01-01T00:00:00.000Z",
            "Data Scadenza": "1753-01-01T00:00:00.000Z",
            "Protocollo": "",
            "Autorizzazione": "",
            "Ricetta": "",
            "Altro": "",
            "Numerazione": "",
            "Bloccato": 0,
            "ID_Utente": "LINDE\\IT00F4",
            "Flusso Strumenti": 0,
            "Flusso Ossigeno": 0,
            "Parente stretto": "",
            "MedicoImport": "",
            "ProdottoImport": "",
            "Diagnosi": "",
            "SospesoImport": "",
            "StrumentoImport": "",
            "DescrStrumento": "",
            "FRI": 0,
            "ORI": 0,
            "Informazioni Ambientali": "",
            "Unità Operativa": "",
            "Flusso Accessori": 0,
            "ASLN": "",
            "DistrettoN": "",
            "Totale Sospeso": 0,
            "Tot Sospeso FT": 0,
            "Dotazione": 0,
            "Usa Consumo Reale": 0,
            "Conta": 0,
            "Nr_ Farmacia": "",
            "Tipo Ventilazione": 0,
            "Tipo di Servizio": 0,
            "Tipologia": 1,
            "Erma": 0,
            "Ult_ Cons_ POT": "1753-01-01T00:00:00.000Z",
            "Note Palmare": "",
            "Provenienza": "",
            "ShortDim3": "ASL",
            "ShortDim4": "020400",
            "ShortDim5": "GOX",
            "ShortDim6": "010909000",
            "ShortDim9": "",
            "ShortDim10": "P260347",
            "Shortdim12": "TM",
            "Frazione": "",
            "Zona": "",
            "Venditore": "",
            "Filiale": "",
            "Agente": "",
            "ASLOLD": "",
            "DistrettoOLD": "",
            "SomministrazioneOld": "",
            "MedicoOLD": "",
            "CatPAZOLD": "",
            "StrumentoOLD": "",
            "Sync Date Modified": "2019-05-08T10:52:15.283Z",
            "First Name": "LUIGI",
            "Middle Name": "",
            "Surname": "MERALDI",
            "Initials": "",
            "Installation Module": 0,
            "ASL Code": "",
            "Città Nascita": "",
            "CAP Nascita": "",
            "E-mail": "",
            "Data ultima assistenza": "1753-01-01T00:00:00.000Z",
            "Patient Type": 1,
            "STP Code": "",
            "CAP Iscr_ Sanitaria": "",
            "City Iscr_ Sanitaria": "",
            "Indirizzo Residenza": "VIA CARDUCCI 16C",
            "Città Residenza": "PORTALBERA",
            "CAP Residenza": "27040",
            "Provincia Residenza": "PV",
            "Cod_ Regione Residenza": "LOM",
            "Codice Paese Residenza": "IT",
            "Standard Next Deliv_ Date": 0,
            "User Filter Dim_ 1": "DOM221000",
            "Patient Id": "",
            "Patient Profile Code": "",
            "Istat Code": "018118",
            "Patologia": "",
            "RecID": {
                "type": "Buffer",
                "data": [
                    96,
                    234,
                    0,
                    0,
                    2,
                    123,
                    255,
                    80,
                    0,
                    50,
                    0,
                    54,
                    0,
                    48,
                    0,
                    51,
                    0,
                    52,
                    0,
                    55,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0
                ]
            },
            "Range Of Supports Code": "",
            "Service Starting Date": "1753-01-01T00:00:00.000Z",
            "Service Expiration Date": "1753-01-01T00:00:00.000Z",
            "Service Item No_": "",
            "Service Order No_": "",
            "RecGUID": "06A7233E-F5E0-4637-8EE9-DB680681EC0A",
            "Delivery Type": ""
        }
    ],
    "message": "data retrieved successfully"
}
```

Comment: The model you are trying to serialize into has property names with accents, 
Is this intentional? If so, I am not sure why you would need to remove accents etc.  ?

Comment: You are right. I have to talk to my team leader to decide what requirement should be changed, the one on the model or the one regarding the removal of accents. Let's assume that the model is wrong and I have to remove accents too.

Comment: I just realize that I copied the wrong API Response.  I've edited and corrected the error. That was a response for the Item API resource, not for the Patient. Another API on wich I have to work.  Of course anything changes in the question.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it is enough to simply tell you that the examples would work on  any property?

```
     [JsonProperty("Global Dimension 1 Code")]
    public string GlobalDimension1Code {get;set;}

[JsonProperty("Unità Operativa")]
        public string UnitOperativa { get; set; }
```

It will map the "odd" named property from the string into the "correct" named property you have in your model.

And then simply not having the properties you wish to ignore on your model, will remove them from the object.

I am still a bit confused about the task presented here, as your wording is a bit strange? But  this should solve your problem yes?
If not, please elaborate on why not.

I don't see a scenario, where it would be relevant to attempt to alter property names, in this manner, when you can just enable the mapping as a property on the model yes?

you would even only need to execute:

```
var responseData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<APILindeResponseWrapper<PatientData>>(apiResponse);
```

Comment: The point is that I can't touch my models, because I use them also to deserialize data that come from another source (excel), not only from API. And I would prefer to don't duplicate as long as the source changes beacuase I want to reuse the validation code. So I've tried to first modify the string response, then to deserialize in the desired Patient data format but that ContractResolver does not work

Comment: I am a bit confused, if you wish to resolve another type of patientData, lets call it, PatientDataAdvanced, that object will have different properties defined, (and likely a different source) You would also have to define said Model for the Specific instance of APILindeResponseWrapper<PatientData>>Which would need to be APILindeResponseWrapper<PatientDataAdvanced>>... If I understand you correctly, you aren't actually avoiding this problem, with your proposed solution?

Comment: Perhaps this answer would also solve your problem?  

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43714050/multiple-jsonproperty-name-assigned-to-single-property

Comment: I am trying to find a way to modify the response in reverse engineering, instead of duplicate the `PatientData` model implementing a `PatientDataAdvanced` model. That's beacause I want to re-use validation code and preserve modularity

Comment: I finally used the method  in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43714050/multiple-jsonproperty-name-assigned-to-single-property